# How do I give Azure Pipelines access to network resources?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a pipeline to include steps such as deploy a dacpac as well as run some e2e integration smoke tests.  Unfortunately, some of the resources are inside of an on-premise network.  How would Azure Pipelines obtain access to network resources?

Comment: just deploy self-hosted agents inside your network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. If you need access to on-premise resources, install and configure a private agent within your network.