# Is it possible to connect azure pipelines to on premise servers?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm migrating from Jenkins, Bitbucket, and Jira to Azure DevOps. I would like to use azure pipelines and connect on my on-premise server, deploy my application, run SonarQube, etc

I've tried to run a local agent on my machine, but I couldn't run a deploy.

---

Solved:
It's possible.
All you need is a self-hosted agent and a deployment group.
In my pipeline **build** I used the following tasks:
MSBuild@1
PublishBuildArtifacts@1
Then in **Release** Pipeline:
IIS Deployment

Comment: You can configure self hosted agent. what did you try and what is "couldn't run a deploy"?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to run MSBuild by cmd as administrator using Azure pipelines

Comment: Why you should run as administrator? please share you build pipeline and which error you got.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give Azure Pipelines access to network resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547579/how-do-i-give-azure-pipelines-access-to-network-resources)

Comment: I was trying to deploy using cmd. Now I'm trying using the tasks.
Error:
Job Job: Step references task 'IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup' at version '0.0.56' which is not valid for the given job target.

PipeLine : https://gist.github.com/BordalloG/7aa6d98d746c8b856e46a48ae1aa9c0a

Comment: @GuilhermeBordallo Do you have IIS enabled on your machine?

Comment: I do and I do have a Site running too.

Comment: It was missing a deployment group. I Appreciate your help @ShaykiAbramczyk !

Comment: You are right! the iis deploy is only for deployment group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved**:
It's possible.
All you need is a self-hosted agent and a deployment group. In my pipeline build I used the  following tasks:
MSBuild@1
PublishBuildArtifacts@1
Then in Release Pipeline:
IIS Deployment

Answer (score 6):

You will need to run a deployment agent on-premises if you want to be able to deploy to servers that you have.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deploying-to-on-premises-environments-with-visual-studio-team-services-or-team-foundation-server/

With that said, when you ran through the configuration did you setup the local agent you created in a pool? Did you assign the local agent to a build group and deployment group?

Did you follow the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops