# Azure DevOps CI/CD for On prem and Cloud Application

Tags: azure, jenkins, deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have to Create CI/CD Pipelines for both On prem and cloud Application,

For Onprem I will use self agent, Cloud i will use Azure Devops provided agent like ubuntu,

I want to implement CI/CD On prem and cloud with  robust and easiest methods that adhere industry standards regardless of tools(Like Azure DevOps, jenkins, Circle CI, etc)

Option 1:

1. Create Separate Pipelines for Onprem with self hosted agent and perform all build, tests in self hosted agent and deploy the services
2. Create separate Pipelines for Cloud application with azure provided agent and tools perform build, tests and deploy applications

Drawback: I am thinking

1. Manageability will be difficult because of two separate CI/CD pipelines

Option 2:

1. Create single CI/CD pipeline, perform build, tests, and deploy to cloud and Onprem servers

Not sure this will possible to connect onprem and push code to on prem machines

Option 3:

1. Add self hosted on prem agent and  Create single CI/CD pipeline for On prem and cloud, perform build, tests and deploy to On prem and cloud applications

Or Any other approach?

It will really great someone share me documentation for CI/CD for both on prem and Cloud applications deployments,

I am able to find the documentation for On prem and cloud applications separately. I am not sure how other companies handles

Comment: I will accept the answer, if i get link to deploy services from both Onprem and cloud, All your links has solution for onprem deployments, which pretty much available in simple search, but it would great if any documentation on deploying onprem and cloud (Better if multi could)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure DevOps CI/CD for On prem and Cloud Application

I agree more with the option 3.

Whether your environments are on-premises or hosted in any cloud, Azure devops and Team Foundation Server make it simple to deploy to any of your environments **using private agents**.

Besides, if you have multiple Onprem servers, we could also use the [deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops).

There are many documents about how to deploy solutions on-premise services using Azure devops:

[DEPLOY SOLUTIONS TO ON-PREMISE SERVERS USING AZURE DEVOPS](https://www.anupams.net/deploy-to-on-premise-devops/)

[Is it possible to connect azure pipelines to on premise servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561448/is-it-possible-to-connect-azure-pipelines-to-on-premise-servers)

[Automating deployments to on premise servers with Azure DevOps](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automating-deployments-to-on-premis-servers-with-azure-devops-bb0e6cac4656)

And a video about [Deploying to On-Premises Servers with VSTS](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/DevOps-Lab/DeployingtoOnPremisesServerswithVSTS)