# Azure DevOps deployment into on premises machine

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-deployment

I have a client that want us to do a deployment into their on premises machine. However, they are not given me much information about the server it self and want to know what they need to do in the server.

First, I asked them to allow some IPs as per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with) , and also to run the Registration script (PowerShell) generated by the DevOps deployment pool.

I am not sure if the script alone will work without the IPs enabled or if I need both.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure DevOps agent only talks over HTTPS to Azure DevOps. The communication is one-way: The agent talks to Azure DevOps. Azure DevOps does not open up a connection to the machine.

As long as the machines can talk to Azure DevOps, you should be fine.

There may be additional configuration necessary depending on what you want to actually *do* with the machine from a deployment perspective, but there's no way anyone can help you with that because you didn't mention what a deployment to that machine may look like.

Answer (score 0):

This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/deploying-azure-vms-deployment-groups?view=azure-devops) demonstrates how to deploy to Azure VMs using deployment groups in Azure Pipelines.

Similarly, if you [create a deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) locally, and then [use IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) in release pipeline then you could deploy into local machine.
[image]

See: [Is it possible to connect azure pipelines to on premise servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561448/is-it-possible-to-connect-azure-pipelines-to-on-premise-servers) and https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automating-deployments-to-on-premis-servers-with-azure-devops-bb0e6cac4656 for details.