# Azure DevOps deploy to on-prem servers?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I am looking on how to do release pipelines to on-prem servers. I have read about self-hosted agents that are part of an agent pool. But I am also reading about deployment groups for target servers. Correct me if I am wrong, but deployment groups seem like a decentralized deployment as each target machine needs the agent installed and is responsible for deploying files onto the same machine. Also I read that deployment groups only work with classic release pipelines. So are deployment groups deprecated? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Apart from classic release pipelines, you can use YAML to author CI/CD pipelines, [Create your first pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser).

> It's possible.
> All you need is a self-hosted agent and a deployment group. In my pipeline build I used the following tasks: MSBuild@1
> PublishBuildArtifacts@1
> Then in Release Pipeline:
> IIS Deployment

You can check availability and upcoming features at [Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline)

References:
[Is it possible to connect azure pipelines to on premise servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561448/is-it-possible-to-connect-azure-pipelines-to-on-premise-servers)

[Automating deployments to on premise servers with Azure DevOps](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automating-deployments-to-on-premis-servers-with-azure-devops-bb0e6cac4656)

Comment: Please refrain from posting link-only answers. Also, the question itself is off-topic (it's a documentation/offsite-resource request question).