# Is it allowed to establish a VPN connection to my Data Center from Azure-Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I am thinking of moving from TFS in our local Data Center to Azure DevOps but one of our pipelines deploys to a server that is going to stay in our Data Center, and that's not exposed to the internet.  Can I establish a VPN with Azure DevOps such that in this multi-tenant environment the pipeline can deploy to our internal server?  Or am I stuck with TFS installed here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give Azure Pipelines access to network resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547579/how-do-i-give-azure-pipelines-access-to-network-resources)

Comment: Like Daniel said, it would probably be easiest to create a self-hosted agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using Deployment groups. The connection will be initiated by your servers.

[image]

For seeing how it work watch the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58UfRxxAWhE